# Discord.py How to get a Command to ignore an argument

Tags: python, arguments, discord, bots

So I want to make a command that can reply to either  .invites   or  .invites @user

When I run this command as .invites, my error handler kicks in and says I need a @user.

I tried removing my error handler and the command does nothing.

How can I make this command work both ways?

```
@commands.command()
    async def invites(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):
        global last1
        global invites1
        try:
            userinvitecount = 0
            gld = self.bot.get_guild(int(guild_id))
            while True:
                invs = await gld.invites()
                tmp = []
                for i in invs:
                    if user.id == i.inviter.id:
                        top = i.uses
                        userinvitecount += int(top)

                    tmp.append(tuple((i.inviter.id, i.code, i.uses)))
                invites1 = tmp
                break
            usr = gld.get_member(int(user.id))
            eme = discord.Embed(description=f"{usr.mention} has {userinvitecount} invite's", color=0x03d692, title=" ")
            await ctx.send(embed=eme)
        except commands.MissingRequiredArgument:
            user = ctx.message.author.id
            userinvitecount = 0
            gld = self.bot.get_guild(int(guild_id))
            while True:
                invs = await gld.invites()
                tmp = []
                for i in invs:
                    if user.id == i.inviter.id:
                        top = i.uses
                        userinvitecount += int(top)

                    tmp.append(tuple((i.inviter.id, i.code, i.uses)))
                invites1 = tmp
                break
            usr = gld.get_member(int(user.id))
            eme = discord.Embed(description=f"{usr.mention} has {userinvitecount} invite's", color=0x03d692, title=" ")
            await ctx.send(embed=eme)
```

```
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        # generic error handler for commands entered wrong
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Failed",
            description="Failed to use command properly \n Please try again.",
            colour=discord.Colour.blurple(),
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using **default** values.
In your command you can then simply check whether **user is None** or not.

Default values can be used e.g. by setting user to `None` like seen below.

```py
@commands.command()
async def invites(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
```

Comment: ```
@commands.command()
    async def invites(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        if user is None:
            user = ctx.message.author
```
Worked perfect thank you